# Why eligible for bounty after two days? - I want solution now for some of my reputation score

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584465/delete-row-from-listview-on-dialouge-boxs-button-click) on stackoverflow. The question was fairly complex and I couldn't find any solution after a whole day. I really wanted solution for the question even after compromising with my reputation score. Why bounty on question is eligible after two days...I think it is a long period. After two days, one would have to compromise with some other solution and no one really wants their typical problems can not be solved up to two days.

This website has helped me much for finding many solutions from intelligent people. if I want to give reputation for an answer to find early solution of a complex problem, putting bounty is really helpful to me. But after two days, it is useless because at that time I would have been compromised by some bad y solution or no solution.

So please make amount of time less for putting bounty...2 to 3 hours are enough.

Comment: Regardless of the complexity, questions on SE are not guaranteed to get quick answers.  But if someone eventually gives you an excellent answer, you can award a bounty to that specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is so that your question might get answered first. Applying a bounty is mainly to draw attention to your question, but when it is first posted it will be on the home page anyway, so no extra attention needs to be brought to it.